# Twig: How to remove twig tags from external string in PHP?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, escaping

Do not ask me why, but I have strings from an external source which are interpreted and I want to strip or escape all possible twig tags from it (external user should not be allowed to use twig).

Example:

```
<h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>

<div class="row">
    {% for product in products %}
    <span class="mep"></span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Desired result:

```
<h1></h1>

<div class="row">
<span class="mep"></span>
</div>
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Use regex? Are you wanting to remove the contents between the twig as well, or just the tags?

Comment: @Alex.Barylski Yes however there might be a better or easier way?

Comment: You could use the Twig parser itself or a project like: https://github.com/eexit/twig-context-parser???

Comment: use regex, `preg_replace` : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: maybe that will help you https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/215/how-can-i-escape-twig-code-to-prevent-it-from-being-parsed

Comment: use regex? but seriously, why would you do that lol ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the Twig tags (as described [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#escaping)) using `{{ '{{' }}`, `{{ '}}' }}`, `{{ '{%' }}` and `{{ '%}' }}`.

```
$input = '<h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>

<div class="row">
    {% for product in products %}
    <span class="mep"></span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>';

$search = "/({{|}}|{%|%})/";

$replace = "{{ '$1' }}";

echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $input);
```

Comment: Thx thats useful, too.

Answer (score 0):

My regex solution (better solution still welcome):

```
$input = '<h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>

<div class="row">
    {% for product in products %}
    <span class="mep"></span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>';

$search = '/({{.+}})|({%.+%})/si';

$replace = '';

echo preg_replace($input, $search, $replace);
```